Power automate flows start by themselves

I have created 15 power automate flows (in Development environment).  They all designed
in a analogous manner - triggered by "When Http Request is received" and then call SQL
Server stored procedure to insert the data specified in the Http Request body.  The
trigger is supposed to be initiated from the Azure Data Factory pipelines and it works
correctly as expected.

I needed to move my flows to Prod environment, so I
a.) Created a 'Solution' -> Added all the flows to a solution.  Retested the flows, and
still everything works.
b) Exported the solution -> Imported the Solution in "Prod" environment.
At this point, I am not clear what it means "Managed vs. unmanaged" flows, but Power
automate was offering some choices, and I think, I specified "Unmanaged".
c.) The Import took the db connection, and created a 'Connection reference'.
d.) In production everything is working as expected.


However, for some reason, my flows in Development environment keep getting triggered and they are constantly in the "Running" state.  What is more, there seem to be created Multiple runs of the flows.
I went ahead to remove flows from the Solution in "Development" and deleted the Solution then.  It did NOT help.  The flows are still being started - nothing is running the ADF that is supposed to trigger them.
If I disable to the flow (Turn Off) it will stop behaving that way, but  when I turn it back on - it keeps doing it again.
This creates a performance issue in the whole environment, as the On Premise Gateway, is used by many other things.  How can I keep the flows, but stop them from being run ?  How do I find what triggers them?  I do need to keep the flows as I work in the ADF, and they need to be run on demand - not permanently.

It's one of two things, either your dev ADF pipelines are still calling the flows or your prod ones are.  Also, managed vs unmanaged is important, you want prod to be managed and dev to be unmanaged.  That's the typical approach.

You can check the trigger on the output of the trigger action, just open the run instance from your flow's main page.
If it is not helping, you can modify your flow to add a 'Terminate' action right after the trigger action, so it will not take up resources despite the continuously starting state.
